# Question about L'Hôpital hypotheses: function that diverges oscillating

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I read the following version of  L'Hôpital  Rule:

Let $f,g: A  \subset \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ two derivable functions in an open set, and let $a\in A$ such that one of the following conditions holds:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$$
$$f \quad \text{and} \quad g  \quad \text{diverge  as} \quad x\to a$$

Then, if $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, so does $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ and they are the same.

I know that the conditions of the existence of $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ means it is finite or $\pm\infty$. Previously, I studied another version which had the condition that $g'(x)\ne 0$ near $a$, but I though about it and conclude that this condition is actually assured if we have that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists.

I have only one last doubt that is bugging me. When the theorem says that $f$ and $g$ are divergent, is it supposed to include the case of a function that diverges but does not diverge neither to $\infty$ nor to $\infty$? Think of a function like $f(x) = x\sin{(x)}$. It diverges (the norm goes to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty$), but it does not diverge neither to $\infty$ nor to $\infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have it, the statement is false. The correct condition is "$f$ and $g$ diverge *to $\infty$ or $-\infty$*". If $f$ and $g$ diverge in other fashions, L'Hopital's rule cannot be guaranteed to hold. Whether $g'(x) \ne 0$ near $a$ needs to be explicitly stated depends on how exactly the limit is defined. If it only is concerned with $x$ within the domain of the function instead of demanding that the function be defined everywhere in a neighborhood of $a$, then you do need to explicitly restrict $g'$ to not be $0$.